# request vacío en node js

Tags: nodejs, formularios, express, handlebars.js

Tengo instalado un node js con express y handlebars y dos formularios.
El primer fomulario es para realizar un login y el segundo un registro de un nuevo usuario.

El primer formulario me funciona correctamente, pero el segundo, no consigo que en su ruta el obj req no sea null y no entiendo el porqué.

Este es el código del archivo registro.hbr

```
        <div class="login-page">
  <div class="form">
    <form class="login-form" name="register" method="POST" action="/register_success">
      <input type="text" placeholder="email" required/>
      <input type="password" placeholder="password" required/>
      <input type="text" placeholder="nombre"/>
      <input type="submit" value="Crear cuenta" name="register_success"></input>
      <p class="message">Ya registrado? <a href="#">Entrar</a></p>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Y este es el enrutador que tengo configurado en node js

```
rutas.post('/register_success', (req, resp)=>{
console.log(req.body);
const email = req.body.email;
const nombre = req.body.name;
const password = req.body.password;

firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(user=>{
    resp.send('Usuario creado con exito');
}).catch(function(error) {
    // Handle Errors here.
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;
    resp.render('loginError');
  });    
});
```

El problema es que el req está siempre vacío y desconozco exactamente el motivo y cómo puedo trazarlo para encontrar dónde se produce el error.

Este es el código del formulario que sí funciona y que se encuentra en index.hbs

```
    <div class="login-page">
  <div class="form">
    <form class="login-form" name="login" method="POST" action="/login">
      <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="email"required/>
      <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" required/>
      <input type="submit" value="Login" name="login"></input>
      <p class="message">No registrado? <a href="register">Crea una cuenta</a></p>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Y ésta su ruta

```
rutas.post('/login', (req, resp)=>{
console.log(req.body);
const email = req.body.email;
const password = req.body.password;
var res;

firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then((user)=>{
    run().catch(error => console.error(error.stack));
    async function run() {
        res = await qr.toDataURL(email);
        resp.render('login', {res:res});
    }
}).catch(function(error) {
    // Handle Errors here.
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;
    resp.render('loginError');
});
```

});

Agradezco su ayuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prueba colocar El NAME en los imput HTML ya que el  el formulario los envia con   la serializacion,  de todas maneras si no funciona, te recomiendo que utilices jquery y ajax, para pegarle al post.

```
<form class="login-form" name="register" method="POST" action="/register_success">
      <input type="text" placeholder="email" name="email" required/>
      <input type="password" placeholder="password"name="password" required/>
      <input type="text" placeholder="nombre" name="nombre" />
      <input type="submit" value="Crear cuenta"></input>
      <p class="message">Ya registrado? <a href="#">Entrar</a></p>
    </form>
```

Comment: Todos los inputs llevan la propiedad name excepto el submit. Se la he añadido y tampoco funciona. Respecto a añadir jquery y ajax, cuál es la ventaja en un formulario tan simple?

Comment: es que no se si se puede hacer esto que tu quieres hacer con node... yo lo eh echo asi con php...

Comment: Gracias... tiene que poderse, ya que el primer formulario funciona, pero el segundo, no.

Comment: haber sube, el codigo del primer formulario que funciona y te ayudamos,

Comment: He actualizado el post con el formulario que sí funciona. Gracias.

Comment: no to que lo que te falta es eso, el  Name en los inputs   es la única diferencia.

Comment: Tienes razón... y lo he mirado 80 veces y veía el name en los inputs... parece ser que estaba todo el rato mirando el formulario que no era.... gracias por la paciencia, pero a veces por mucho que miras, no ves las cosas.

Comment: Genial avisa si te funciona.